# Reliable background queuing for task on IIS

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to implement a queue to handle tasks queued by using task.run(function()).

Here are my requirements:

1) The threadpool should not stop after the application context has died. I need to be sure the calls will be made. (I believe this requires the thread to be a foreground thread)

2) Additionally, I need to be able to log these errors. Each function has it own error handling implemented within. I would consider it a fire and forget because I don't actually need to pass the data back to the caller but the information needs to be logged.

3) The queue will remove tasks as they complete. I may need some way of managing the size of the queue to prevent overuse of resources. Possibly, able to set a time limit for each task and forcing it to cancel after allotted time to free space queue.

Specification: 
- .Net 4.0 Framework 
- IIS

Comment: no, cannot be done, don't even bother to try. Use windows service instead

Comment: 1) is not possible.  Besides, web sites are not designed to continue to run (or magically self-start)  if nothing is "looking" at it.  Think of a mouse and the Moon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question to solve

Comment: Can you offer suggestions to my requirements that can make another version of this possible?

Comment: @DaqueshiaIrvin I think my first comment was clear enough. It cannot be done with IIS, use windows service instead. or a separate exe

Comment: @Steve I'll rephrase my question, which of these requirements are making this not able to be done?

Comment: @DaqueshiaIrvin 1 and 2 cannot be done, 3 doesn't make any sense if 1, 2 are not doable so basically all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desire functionality by referencing Stephen Cleary [AspNetBackgroundTasks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks)

By using a singleton pattern, I was able to create a single instance of a object which is used as wrapper for managing the task. The code is able to prevent shut down by using the iregisteredobject.

Upon receiving a notification of pending shut down, Asp.Net notifies the object. Using a TaskCompleteSource, which only updates its state to a completed state when the running tasks count equal zero, the application await for all task to finish before allowing the application to shutdown.

There are risk in this design. The risk that is very similar to notification systems currently running in main memory. If power is lost, the code is lost.

Additionally, remember to make atomic changes to shared variables or implement thread safe locking techniques.